# How should I create a table in Latex?

Tags: tables, multirow, multicolumn

I'm facing a bit trouble in creating tables in latex using `\multirow` and `\multicolumn` keywords.

[image]

It would be great if anyone can help me out to create just like above table using latex. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. In particular, please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some suggestions

- Use `l` ("left-aligned") column type for the first column, and `c` ("centered") for the 7 data columns
- Use `\multicolumn` in three separate places
- No need for `\multirow` anywhere, AFAICT
- To give the table an open and inviting look, use no vertical bars, and draw only a few, but well-spaced, horizontal lines. Load the `booktabs` package for the macros `\toprule`, `\midrule`, `\cmidrule`, and `\bottomrule`.
- Load the `siunitx` package and employ its `SI` macro to typeset numbers and their associated units.
- Optional: Load the `helvet` package to set the default sans-serif font to a Helvetica clone.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,siunitx}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{helvet} % use Helvetica clone for sans-serif
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\sffamily % optional?switch to sans-serif for table
\sisetup{detect-all}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l *{7}{c} @{}}
\toprule
S. no. & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Time Domain}
       & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{Frequency Domain} \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(l){5-8}
& Input V1 & Input V2 & Output V0 
& Input V1 & Input V2 & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Output V0} \\
\midrule
1 & \SI{3}{\volt} & \SI{3}{\volt} & \SI{5.79}{\volt}
  & \SI{3}{\volt} & \SI{3}{\volt} & \SI{-400}{\milli\decibel v} 
  & \SI{-400}{\milli\decibel v} \\
2 & \SI{1}{\volt} & \SI{2}{\volt} & \SI{2.89}{\volt}
  & \SI{1}{\volt} & \SI{2}{\volt} & \SI{-3.2}{\decibel v} 
  & \SI{-10.8}{\decibel v} \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```